# Django User model extended for employee. How to access the employee attribute in change_form of model admin?

Tags: python, django

Django 1.6.5. I have extended the User model to create model Employee using foreign key 1:1 as follows:

```
class Employee(models.Model):
   user = models.OneToOneField(User)
   extension = models.CharField(max_length=2)
```

I wish to access value of `extension` in the `model admin change_form.html` using request object. How do I do it. I am not using any custom view. I am using TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS in settings.py with tuple values as:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
 'django.core.context_processors.request',
 'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by setting the related_name argument for the OneToOneField.

> user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name="employee_profile")

To access the extension field, you use

> request.user.employee_profile.extension